# Performance issue when updating one table based on another

Tags: mysql

Given:

| TableA | Table B |
| --- | --- |
| guid | guid |
| missing |  |

Table A  ~400k rows
Table B  ~150k rows

Both tables have the same guids but I need to mark in A all the missing guids from B. Both guids have indexes.

Query:

```
update table_a
         left join table_b b on table_a.guid = b.guid
set missing = true
where b.guid is null;
```

This query works but took 4,5 hours on my machine. Is there any way I can make this query run faster?

**UPD:**

All three answers below gave me some tips to think on.
The following query ran for 8 seconds.

```
update table_a a
set missing = true
where a.guid not in (
    select a.guid
    from table_b b,
         table_a a
    where b.guid = a.guid
);
```

Comment: [UUIDs are bad for performance](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/22/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how data stored and I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

its much faster. it only tests if the ROW xists.

```
UPDATE table_a ta
SET missing = true
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from table_b tb WHERE ta.guid = tb.guid );
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `table_b` have an index starting with `guid`?  (A `PRIMARY KEY` is an INDEX.)

Do you need to run this query frequently?  Let's get rid of it after this initial update.  In the future, whenever you modify table_b, reach over and update `table_a`.  `TRIGGERs` might be a good way to do such.  A `DELETE TRIGGER` could set `missing=1`; an `INSERT TRIGGER` (etc)

In, instead, you choose to run the `UPDATE` repeatedly, see this for how to chunk the action, etc:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Another approach is to check for whether the row is "missing" by a `LEFT JOIN` in the `SELECT`, not by having the column.

Comment: Indexes not started with `guid`. I need to run it once in a while.

Comment: @user3841429 - "Once in a while" -- Then do the chunking I advise and don't worry about optimization.

Comment: You mentioned triggers. I forgot to mention that `guid` is not a primary key. Both of those tables have incremental ids. How would I trigger set `missing=true` in `talble_a` if I replace `guid` in `table_b` ? Ex: `update table_b set guid={new_guid} where id={id}`. (I'm checking your website. It's awesome. A lot of stuff I have to learn!)

Comment: @user3841429 - Thanks.  You may have noticed that I have a UUID/GUID page; it was created independently of Percona's; there is a lot of overlap but from different viewpoints.  I sketched out how to do it with Triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `TRIGGERs` would be something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER del BEFORE DELETE ON table_b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_a
        SET missing = true
        WHERE guid = OLD.guid;   -- or maybe test id??
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

And one for `INSERT`.  And one for `UPDATEs` if you might change `guid`.  This would need a two commands for `UPDATE table_a` -- one for the old guid (a la Delete), one for the new (a la Insert).

These would add a small burden when table_b is modified, but probably not enough to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update table_a
set missing = true
where guid not in (select guid from table_b)
```